# SPD Workflow to find item by "title - XXX"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Upon creation of an item in my calendar list, a task is created for some users. The title given to this task is the title of the calendar event plus a three letter company ID. Eg. "ABC Task". 
When the task is complete I need the original event in the calendar to be updated - simple checking a yes/no box. Is there a way of me finding the list item by the title without the three letter ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered adding a lookup column in the Tasks list connecting the actual Calendar, something like "Related Event". You would set the value of the lookup to point to the appropiate Event upon creation of the Task, and use that exact value from the Workflow to update the appropiate item, as here http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/05/09/handling-lookup-columns-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/